# java.sql.Date (YYYY-MM-DD) to java.util.Date (DD-MMM-YYYY) conversion

Tags: java

Need advise how to send the java.sql.Date (YYYY-MM-DD) to java.util.Date (DD-MMM-YYYY).

The class java.sql.Date is designed to carry only a date.  I have a table with column EXPIRY_DATE as DATE data type.

When I do the following

```
rs.getDate("EXPIRY_DATE")
```

it gives the output in the format YYYY-MM-DD. For example, 2015-04-05

I have a following Java bean

```
class ABC {
     java.util.Date expiryDate;
}
```

I want to return the above bean as it is to the JSP page view as JSON object.  As we are using Spring REST Controller (**@RestController** Service), I wrote the following line,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/url")
class someClass {

@RequestMapping("/url")
Object someWebServiceMethod() {
    ABC object = new ABC();
    object.setExpiryDate( resultSet.getDate("EXPIRY_DATE") );
    return object;
    }
}
```

My webservice returns the date as it is in java.sql.Date format like YYYY-MM-DD.

I want to send the output in DD-MMM-YYYY format to the JSP page view.

How to convert the same?

I have tried the following code,

**NOTE:  The below code is irrelevant to my above question. I need solution only for the above @RestController spring code**

```
public static void convertDate() {
    String input = "2013-09-14";
    // DateFormat format = DateFormat.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
    Date date;
    try {
        date = format1.parse(input);
        String temp = format2.format(date);
        Date outDate = format2.parse(temp);
        System.out.println(outDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But it gives the output as *Mon Jan 14 00:00:00 IST 2013*

**I want to send the date, in the format dd-MMM-YYYY like 28-Feb-2015**

Presently My @RestController code returns the java.sql.Date format like 2015-02-28.  But I want to be 28-Feb-2015.

Please advise how to do java.sql.Date (YYYY-MM-DD) to java.util.Date (DD-MMM-YYYY) conversion

Thanks

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you re-parse the date once it has been formatted.

```
date = format1.parse(input);
String temp = format2.format(date);
Date outDate = format2.parse(temp);
System.out.println(outDate);
```

Simply do

```
date = format1.parse(input);
String temp = format2.format(date);
System.out.println(temp)
```

Note that if you have `JSTL` you can format direcytly in the page:

```
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
```

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${bean.date}" pattern="dd-MMM-yy" />
```

Comment: Sorry for the belated reply.  Yes, the above suggessions worked for me.  :-)  Thank you!!

Comment: I have converted at JSP end using taglib.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to send the output in DD-MMM-YYYY format to the JSP page view.

Then you need to use a `SimpleDateFormat` to do so. Currently you're using the result of `Date.toString()`, and ignoring `temp` which should already have the right result.

However, you shouldn't need to *parse* the `java.sql.Date` at all - you can just pass it straight to `DateFormat.format`:

```
java.sql.Date date = /* get date from database */; 
// TODO: Specify time zone and locale
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String formattedDate = format.format(date);
```

Alternatively, I suspect that JSP already has a mechanism for allowing you to pass the date straight to the JSP itself, and specify the output format there... this is really a conversion to move as close to the presentation layer as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. From your code, I should not return formattedDate as String.  As per your code, formattedDate should be java.util.Date.  Please look at my bean declaration.  I declared my attribute as java.util.Date expiryDate;

Comment: @SaravananSivaji: Then you need to accept that a `Date` value doesn't *have* a format. It's just a point in time. There's no such thing as "a Date in DD-MMM-YY format". It's *crucial* that you understand the difference between a `Date` object and some string representation of it - you're currently saying there's a problem with a string representation, but that you won't be returning a string representation, only the `Date` value. Those two statements are contradictory.

Comment: my convertDate() is just an example sample tried separately.  As you stated, I haven't parsed my java.sql.Date.  I just assign as it is like object.setExpiryDate( resultSet.getDate("EXPIRY_DATE") );  Please see my @RestController spring code.

Comment: @SaravananSivaji: Right, so `convertDate` is irrelevant and you should remove it from the question. But fundamentally you've talked about your JSP converting the data to JSON, so that *is* a string representation. You need to find out exactly where that conversion from `Date` to `String` is being performed, and set the formatting *there*.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DatesTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        String strdate = "2018-07-02";
        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");        
        try {            
            Date oldDate = format1.parse(strdate);
            System.out.println(sdf.format(oldDate));
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DatesTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
    }
    
}
```